# Why i cannot log in successfully?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner for c++ and have some problems here !

currently, i have a text file named "users.txt" and there are a few data stored inside the text file:

```
simon
1234
123123

john
4321
34343

weejay
8888
7777

dicson
4444
3333

kendy
5555
9998
```

At first, users need to enter the username and pincode to login. But, when i run the program it will directly said that i've entered invalid pincode or ID although i've entered correctly. May i know how to solve this ??

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std ;
struct users {
    string name ;
    string pincode ;
    int amount ;

};
int main ()
{
    cin.sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

     string name[10] ;
     string pincode [10];
     int amount [10];

     users obj [10] ;
    ifstream infile("users.txt");
    for (int i=0; i <10 ; i++)
    {
        infile >> name [i];
        infile >> pincode [i];
        infile >> amount [i] ;
    }

    w:
        string username ;
        string password;

        cout <<"enter username : " << endl ;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, username);
        cout << "enter password : " << endl ;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, password );

        bool islogin = false ;
        for (int i=0; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
               if (password == pincode[i] && username == name[i] )
               {
                    cout << "successfully log in ! " << endl ;
                    islogin = true ;
                    break ;
                }else
                {
                    islogin = false ;
                }
        }
        if (!islogin)
        {
            cout << "sorry you have entered invalid pin code or ID  " << endl ;

            cout << "you want to login again " << endl ;
            cout << "1. yes" << endl ;
            cout << "2. no" << endl ;
            char option ;
            cin >> option ;
            if (option == '1')
            {
                system("cls");
                fflush(stdin);
                goto w ;

            }else
            {
                cout << "thanks for using our system " << endl;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `name` and `pincode` contains the data you want? Have you checked what `username` and `password` is? You could do these very easily by just playing `std::cout`s where applicable to print the data, or by using a debugger.

Comment: I suggest you start with forgetting about `goto`. It would be a nice first step. Next, you have `struct users` defined, maype consider using it somehow. Then, `cin.ignore()` doesn't quite do what you think it does. Try not using it.

Comment: See also [How to debug small programs](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/)

Comment: You also need to check that your reads from `infile` are successful and that `infile` opened successfully in the first place

Comment: Why do you use `cin.sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin.ignore()` simply ignores the next character that is read from `cin`. I presume you are trying to `ignore` to solve this problem [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction).

You only need to do this when switching from formatted input (reading using `>>`) to `getline` to ignore the remaining newline in the stream (otherwise `std::getline` returns an empty string). The correct call is: `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`, this ignores all remaining characters in the input up to and including the first newline.

When you read the `username` that is the first time you use `cin` the `ignore()` call simply ignores the first character of the username. Your second `ignore()` ignores the first character of the passcode.

A fully working example is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct users {
    std::string name;
    std::string pincode;
    int amount;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<users> obj;
    std::ifstream infile("users.txt");
    if (!infile)
    {
        std::cout << "users.txt not found\n";
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        users user;
        infile >> user.name;
        infile >> user.pincode;
        infile >> user.amount;
        if (!infile)
        {
            break;
        }
        obj.push_back(user);
    }

    bool islogin = false;
    while (!islogin)
    {
        std::string username;
        std::string password;

        std::cout << "enter username :\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, username);
        std::cout << "enter password :\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, password);

        for (auto& user:obj)
        {
            if (password == user.pincode && username == user.name)
            {
                std::cout << "successfully log in !\n";
                islogin = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                islogin = false;
            }
        }
        if (!islogin)
        {
            std::cout << "sorry you have entered invalid pin code or ID\n";

            std::cout << "you want to login again\n";
            std::cout << "1. yes\n";
            std::cout << "2. no\n";
            char option;
            std::cin >> option;
            if (option == '1')
            {
                system("cls");
                // ignore the newline after 1 so that the next std::getline succeeds
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "thanks for using our system\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```